# How to check if a SpriteNode touches another SpriteNote?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

So what I'm trying to do is a player which is able to jump when he's on the ground but when he's in the air he is not. And to be honest I have no idea how to accomplish this because I'm new to stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have an instance variable in the player class like `var isOnGround: Bool = true`. I would then set up a physics body for the player and the ground using `SKPhysicsBody`. Then check for collisions in the `didBegin(...)` and `didEnd(...)` (contact methods) for the player and the ground. Set the `isOnGround` variable to true in `didBegin(...)` and set it to false in the `didEnd(...)` methods.

Here's an example of the different bit masks properties:

```
let playerCollisionNumber: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let groundCollisionNumber: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

//node's own collision number
player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCollisionNumber 

//makes the player's physics body interact/collide with the ground's physics body
player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = groundCollisionNumber 

//setting this allows you to be able to interject your own code when the player's physics body and the ground's physics body interact (in the didBegin and didEnd methods)
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCollisionNumber
```

Then do the same for the ground:

```
groundNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = groundCollisionNumber
groundNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCollisionNumber
groundNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCollisionNumber
```

You'll set the `isOnGround` variable in the `didBegin()` and `didEnd()` methods like this:

```
let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

//in didBegin()
if contactMask == (playerCollisionNumber | groundCollisionNumber) {
    player.isOnGround = true
}

//in didEnd()
if contactMask == (playerCollisionNumber | groundCollisionNumber) {
    player.isOnGround = false
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to make or use those CatergoryBitMasks or ContactBitMasks.

Comment: @LukasDomeisen, see my updated answer for a brief overview of the bit masks.

Comment: Thanks, could you also show me how to implement the isOnGround Boolean?

Comment: I have a problem in the Line that says: let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
Theres a error saying Use of unresolved identifier "contact"

Comment: Could you help me out on that please?

Comment: It might be best to create a separate question for this, but where are you declaring it?

Comment: In the did move to view Function

Comment: Ah, it needs to be declared in the didBegin and didEnd methods. A contact is generated every time two physics bodies interact with other, and that contact is passed into the didBegin and didEnd methods.

Comment: Oh right, makes sense. But now i have a problem that the player just falls through the ground.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133586/discussion-between-claassenapps-and-lukas-domeisen).